# Understanding "asymptotic" behaviour of a set

Tags: complex-analysis, approximation-theory

In a book, an author defines a complex polynomial 
\begin{align*}
p(z)=\alpha_{n}z^{n}+\alpha_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\cdots+\alpha_{1}z+\alpha_{0},\quad \alpha_{n}\neq0,
\end{align*}
$n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\text{Re }p(z)\geq0$ for $z\in\mathbb{R}$. Further, he claims the set $A=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\text{Re }p(z)<0\}$ "approaches" the following $n$ sectors
\begin{align*}
\arg\alpha_{n}+n\arg z \in \left(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)+2m\pi,\quad m=0,\ldots,n-1,
\end{align*}
for large $|z|$. He says something like $p(z)\approx\alpha_{n}z^{n}$ for large $|z|$, however, what does $\approx$ really mean here? Is there some more explicit way of showing this fact?

Comment: What is $k$ as in " large $|k|$"?

Comment: @Dr.MV fixed it

Comment: So, how does $|p(z)/z^n|$ behave as $|z|\to \infty$?

Comment: It goes to $\alpha_{n}$

Comment: And how does $|p(z)/\alpha_nz^n|$ behave as $|z|\to \infty$?

Comment: What are you trying to say? please be more explicit!

Comment: If $a=b$, $a/b=1$. In this case, the author says $p(z)\approx \alpha_n z^n$ because $p(z)/(\alpha_nz^n)\rightarrow 1$ as $|z|\rightarrow \infty$. That is what Dr. MV is hinting at.

Comment: @par How about the sectors, that was the main question?